# mouseenter + mouseleave events

Tags: javascript, dom, webkit, mouseevent

I just found out that Firefox is natively supporting mouseenter and mouseleave events.

This means we have IE and Firefox support and as soon as webkit jumps on the band wagon we have a cross browser solution (no one cares about Opera in Aus).

My question is, Does anyone know when they will be supporting this event and why they have not done so already?

Its DOM level 3, so its not "proprietary microsoft anymore".

P.S I don't care if it can be done in jQuery, so please don't bother telling me.

Comment: _"no one cares about Opera in Aus"_ - I do.

Comment: Opera(Presto) does support mouseevent/mouseleave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's hard to say as open source projects have a mind of their own, but seeing is how they're the only one left right now I would assume sooner than later.

Here track the bug yourself: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18930

Comment: Thanks dude, I'm never good with finding what I need on those report a bug forums